# React-Native sort array of objects by date value within object

Tags: javascript, react-native

We have an array of objects like this:

```
{key: "T62", currentWinnerName: "Test Register", dateCreated: Fri Jan 18 2019 18:17:50 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)}
{key: "T68", currentWinnerName: "Test Register", dateCreated: Wed Jan 23 2019 14:57:40 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)}
{key: "T58", currentWinnerName: "Test Register", dateCreated: Fri Jan 18 2019 15:57:45 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)}
```

We need to sort the array based on the `dateCreated` value within the array.

I've tried various sort methods but unable to get the order to change.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your object is array. then you can do like this way.

```js
var obj = [
  {
  key: "T62", 
  currentWinnerName: "Test Register", 
  dateCreated: "Fri Jan 18 2019 18:17:50 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"
  },
{
 key: "T68", 
currentWinnerName: "Test Register", 
dateCreated: "Wed Jan 23 2019 14:57:40 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"
},
{
key: "T58", 
currentWinnerName: "Test Register",
 dateCreated: "Fri Jan 18 2019 15:57:45 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)"}
];
let sortedObj =  obj.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.dateCreated) - new Date(a.dateCreated);
});

console.log(sortedObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this :

```
const getTimestamp = (dateString)=> new Date(dateString).getTime();

const isOlder = (object1, object2)=> getTimestamp(object1.dateCreated) < getTimestamp(object2.dateCreated) ? -1 : 1;

const sortedArr = arr.sort(isOlder);
```

`arr` is your array. But you have to make `dateCreated` a string. This worked for me.